# My website font size is changing automatically when loading

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

When I load my website half of the page size is loading different than the other half. This only happen sometimes. This is ruining my website view.

[image: below image attached on same page where half part font size is not loaded half size showing different.]

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using `webfonts` to display text in fonts that aren't on your device. You see the sizes change when a similar looking font that exists on your device is swapped for the webfont when the download completes.

You see this "sometimes" based on caching and or speed of your connection to get and render the fonts.

Comment: This should probably be a comment and not an answer as the OP provides no information whatsoever to even begin to solve this.